# Which pixel format for web mp4 video?

Tags: ffmpeg, html5-video, mp4

I have to create video in mp4 format, and it seems that I can encode it with different pixel formats like `yuv420p`, `yuv422p`, `yuvj422p`. Which one I should use to maximize compatibility with most browsers/players?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

## Use yuv420p

You can use the `-vf format=yuv420p` (or the alias `-pix_fmt yuv420p`) output option to make sure your output is YUV 4:2:0.

#### Example

```
ffmpeg -i input -c:v libx264 -crf 23 -preset medium -vf format=yuv420p -c:a copy -movflags +faststart output.mp4
```

- For web video the `-movflags +faststart` option is also recommended.
- The audio is being [stream copied](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Stream-copy) (re-muxed) in this example instead of being re-encoded. Useful if the input is already AAC.
- See FFmpeg Wiki: [H.264](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/H.264) & [H.265](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/H.265) for more info on the encoder specific settings (`-crf` and `-preset`).

#### Determining the pixel format of a video

You can check the pixel format of a video with `ffprobe`:

```
$ ffprobe -loglevel error -show_entries stream=pix_fmt -of csv=p=0 input.mp4
yuv420p
```

Comment: `ffprobe video.mp4` can be used to check which pixel format is used.

Comment: @l--marcl Thanks,  I added a more specific `ffprobe` example.

Comment: thank you, btw. i have read at http://manpages.org/ffmpeg that the "-movflags +faststart" downside is that it "is less compatible with other applications"

Comment: @16851556 Your quote is about fragmented MP4 files, not about `-movflags +faststart`.